# Installing Ubuntu on a 3 terabyte drive with 2 terabytes allocated to Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

Is is possible to install Ubuntu 12.04 onto a 3 terabyte drive that already has 2 terabytes allocated to Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit?  What I would like to do it use the remaining 750 GB of unallocated space on the drive for Ubuntu.  If this is possible how would I go about completing this installation?

Answer (score 0):

The installation process is similar to ordinary installation process . At the time of installation before selecting partitions it will ask you for what kind of installation you wanna do with some options . so you can choose manual setup(the last one).then select the space you want to give . but 750 GB means very huge man . 30-40 GB is more than enough . so just take the part and give the remaining space to some other partition . one more thing is its always better to have /home as separate one to save your data .